# AS3, (phrase + Integer variable) for Boolean check?

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, integer, boolean

I have a number of functions and variables depending on a particular Integer variable, "i". Is it possible to write a Boolean variable itself as the base phrase plus the integer variable?

For example, something like:

```
["boolCHECK" + i] = true;
```

Instead of:

```
if (i == 1)
{
boolCHECK1 = true;
}
if (i == 2)
{
boolCHECK2 = true;
}
... etc.
```

Comment: I would say there is some issue with code design. If you need to have a boolean value for each index use Vector.<Boolean>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work.  You may get a compiler error though since you're not referencing a known object.  To remedy that, just reference `this`:

```
this["boolCHECK" + i] = true;
```

That said, you should probably just use an array for this scenario as it's cleaner and less prone to typo's.    As pointed out in the comments by @fsbmain, this is a good candidate for a vector:

```
var checks:Vector.<Boolean> = new <Boolean>[true, false, true, false]; //etc

//later
checks[i] = true;
```

Comment: Thanks!, solved. Very sorry, I should have mentioned the compiler errors as well, but using `this` resolved them perfectly.